# No tag for "Adobe Audition"

Tags: discussion, tags

I see there is no tag for the popular tool Audition, though there is for Audacity.  Maybe someone should flesh out some useful tags, since the SE is still in beta?

Answer (score 4):

Tags are driven by questions, not the other way round. So if there is enough demand for a tag we can create it. But there isn't much point creating tags first and then waiting until they are populated.

Do you have a feel for how many questions require this tag? Can you post links to them?